# How can A service of Google Cloud Run for Anthos on GKE connect to Firestore on different project of different organization?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, google-anthos

I made a service of Cloud Run for Anthos on GKE. And Then, I want to make it connect to the Firestore on a Project of a diffrent Organization. How can it make connect to Firestore?

I created a service of Cloud Run for Anthos on GKE on ProjectA of OrganizationA.
The programming language of the service of Cloud Run is Java, google-cloud-firestore library.

And, I created a Firestore DB on ProjectB of OrganizationB(No organization).

And then, tried to acces the Cloud Run Service to FirestoreDB, I got the error message like blow.

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All depends your requirement. According with this [page](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#roles), grant the service account with `roles/datastore.user` or `roles/datastore.viewer` in the IAM section of the project B (click on Add and paste the email of the service account).

According with your GKE deployment, service account can be the default compute service account (`<projectNumber>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) or something else if you have customized your cluster/[workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

Comment: I put roles/datastore.owner on Compute Engine default service account of projectA at projectB IAM. I seems worked, thank you very much!!